# Interface method multiple return types

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have an interface with a method that can return multiple types?

I know there is the dynamic type, or there is

```
public T MyMethod<T>() { }
```

But classes implementing this interface will still complain about incompatible types. I can't use dynamic type in my class implementing the interface because i want the caller to know what kind of result it will receive.

```
public interface Command {
    T Execute<T> ();
}}

public class GetMaxFallSpeedCommand : Command {
    public float Execute() {
        return 1f;
    }
}
```

Return "does not implement interface..."

Concrete usage:

```
void Main() {
    var myClass = new MyClass();
        
    myClass.ExecuteCommand(new MyCommandThatJustDoesSomething());

    float someValue = myClass.ExecuteCommand(new MyCommandThatReturnsAFloat());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean under "But classes implementing this interface will still complain about incompatible types" can you show example? How exactly you implement this interface in some class

Comment: will the implementing classes potentially be returning different types under different circumstances or will a given implementation always return the same type. If it's the second, then the generic interface would be a good fit, and you define your implementing class with the type that it returns.

Comment: Sorry, i updated. No, every class implementing the interface will return a given type.

Comment: You didn't indicate how it would be used so the answer you got was just lucky and it still might lead to "the next problem". How do you handle an object that implements `ICommand<ClassYouDidntKnowExisted>`? And how do you use and instance of `ClassYouDidntKnowExisted` when it's returned?

Comment: It seemed pretty clear to me. I'm simply putting in place a way for a class to pass messages to another class without knowing anything about that class other than what response type (or not) it can expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your command a generic interface, and then when implementing the interface you specify the type of your interface that you are implementing. Your example modified below.

*EDIT:* I changed `ICommand` to `IExecute` because there is already an `ICommand` interface in .NET. Also, I added an interface with no generic type for implementing classes that return void based on the comments on this question.

```cs
public interface IExecute<T>
{
    T Execute();
}

public interface IExecute
{
    void Execute();
}

public class GetMaxFallSpeedCommand : IExecute<float>
{
    public float Execute()
    {
        return 1f;
    }
}

public class DoSomethingReturnNothing : IExecute
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: For OP's benefit, I want to point out that you would need to know what `T` could be and test for that interface, e.g. `ICommand<float>`, or use reflection to find the close-constructed interface that is an `ICommand<T>`. In the reflection case, you're still probably going to be invoking the method dynamically and getting `object` back (and boxing that `float`) so you might as well just have it return `object`.

Comment: This seems to be what i'm looking for. However, sometimes i need my command to not return anything and with void i get "keyword void cannot be used in this contexte".

public class DoSomething : Command<void> {
    public void Execute() {
    }
}}

Comment: Two quick options for that: implement `ICommand<object>` and the `Execute` method returns `null` (or a null object if you prefer), or define `ICommand` (no type parameter) and it returns `void`. The close-constructed interfaces are already distinct from each other so a non-generic interface for no return value is just one more distinct interface.